Add query results straight to form instead of a new table and in a set format
I have successfully created a query, the outcome of the query is to create a unique id in the database, and am able to run it as an embedded macro.
The outcome of the query is each row appears as 'ID 1', 'ID 2' etc.
What I am trying to do is have the results of the query appear in the ID field of the form, instead of in a new table where i have to then copy and paste the results across.
In my current query, the field reads ScammerID: "ID" & "-" & [TableID]
(I want the 'output' to be ID - 0001
I have tried changing the query to an append query, but it comes up with a syntax error.
I have also tried an update query, also with a syntax error.

You can use this expression with Format:
ScammerID: Format([TableID],"I\D - 0000")


Thank you for that.  This works in giving me the format I want.  I'm struggling to have the query results entered into the relevant part of the form, instead of having to copy and past the results into the table manually afterwards

Bind the textbox on the form to ScammerID of the query. You should not save calculated values in the table.
